# running an Elixir program on Heroku in cloud

Tags: linux, heroku, elixir, cloud

I am not a programmer so please bear with me. I would love to play  a sailing simulation at https://8bitbyte.ca/sailnavsim . In order for my boat not to crash into the shore while I am sleeping I need to install an autopilot. There is one on github:
https://github.com/ghislain-l/gpilot

unfortunately I do not have an extra machine I could dedicate to Linux and also no possibility of running a VM at home. I was thinking of running the whole thing in the cloud to also learn a bit how to do that - I am not a programmer and very old and rusty. So I have opened a Heroku account and made the connection to Github, set up a fork from the Github page and tried to deploy the Autopilot program using Herokus tools. However, this failed. I have no idea why and I cannot figure out how to do it using command line stuff. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The Github page says to install to upload the files to the /ops directory/folder and then do something else for it to run. I have no idea how to do that on Heroku. Another difficulty seems to be that the program is written in Elixir and it seems that Heroku does not directly support that.

Please be gentle  :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. We're not here to replace tutorials or documentation. This is too broad to be on-topic here.

Comment: Having said that, Heroku isn't a VPS. You don't put things into directories. It's a platform-as-a-service provider. You provide application code and instructions for building the application, usually in the form of declared dependencies and an entrypoint, and it does the rest. You are correct that Heroku doesn't offer first-class support for Elixir. Your options are to use [a third-party buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=elixir), to build a Docker container, or to select another hosting provider. Given the instructions you reference, a VPS might be a better choice.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for your help. If there is a different forum or website where I should be asking such questions I would appreciate if you pointed me in that direction. I landed here from Heroku help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

That gpilot application has a deploy strategy that is incompatible with Heroku. But the good news is that you can change that.

You need to follow [these instructions](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/hashnuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir) to prepare the app for use on Heroku and do some configuration.

Eventually Heroku will look for a `Procfile` to start the application. If that file is not present it will just run `mix run --no-halt` which should be ok.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Hi thank you very much I have found this buildpack but I cannot figure it out. I guess I will try to find a different VPS provider.